# SQL Server Dba Simulation

Tags: sql-server, load, performance-testing, database-performance, database-administration

I'm looking into creating a SQL Server database and then creating some T-SQL scripts which simulate stress/ a load on the database. Which I can then investigate using windows performance monitor, to highlight the causes of the load, and how to fix it. The aim of this is to train an ability to investigate database performance problems and how to fix them.

I'm new to database administration but I can't seem to find many resources/information on performance and creating fake loads to test performance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've found some articles on how to over load the CPU but I really can't find much material about creating database performance problems and then fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

**[SQL Query Stress](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlQueryStress)** - allows you to simulate load by executing queries repeatedly.

**[Diskspd](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223)** - test I/O subsystem

If you need some data to test against you are also free to download the StackOverflow database and put it on your test server. Here's a **[LINK](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/)** to a post on how to download the database.

Comment: If I wanted to create the scripts myself, how would I go about doing that? I can't seem to find much information on that myself?